# Prove expected value of first hitting time is finite for irreducible finite state Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

In Levin and Peres' Markov Chains and Mixing Times, lemma 1.13 states:
For any states $x$ and $y$ of an irreducible chain, $E_x(\tau^+_y)<\infty$ where $\tau^+_x := \min\{t \geq 1 : X_t = x\}$.
The proof in the text is:

The definition of irreducibility implies that there exist an integer $r > 0$
and a real $\epsilon > 0$ with the following property: for any states $z, w \in \mathcal{X}$ , there exists a $j \leq r$ with $P^j(z, w) >\epsilon$. Thus for any value of $X_t$ , the probability of hitting state $y$ at a time between $t$ and $t + r$ is at least $\epsilon$. Hence for $k > 0$ we have (1.17):
\begin{equation}
P_x\{\tau^+_y > kr\} ≤ (1 − \epsilon)P_x\left\{\tau^+_y > (k-1)r\right\}
\end{equation}
Repeated application of (1.17) yields:
$$P_x\{\tau^+_y > kr\} \leq (1 − \epsilon)^k$$
Lastly:
$$E_x(\tau^+_y) =\sum_{t\geq0}P_x\{\tau^+_y  > t\} ≤\sum_{k\geq0}rP_x\{\tau^+_y> kr\}≤ r(1 − \epsilon)^k <\infty.$$

How do we prove (1.17)?. It seems induction is the way to go. (1.17) holds when $k=1$ but showing that (1.17) holds for $k+1$ if it holds for $k$ is more complicated. Also in the last sentence of the proof, why is the first inequality true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first inequality is using two observations:

1. Over the course of the first $r$ time steps, you have probability at least $\epsilon$ to hit $y$.
2. If you didn't hit $y$ in the first $r$ time steps, regardless of where you ended up, over the course of the next $r$ time steps you have probability at least $\epsilon$ to hit $y$.

In symbols, we write $P_x(\tau_y^+>kr)=P_x(\tau_y^+>kr \mid \tau_y^+>(k-1)r) P_x(\tau_y^+>(k-1)r)$. We get the first inequality by noticing that the first factor is less than $1-\epsilon$, and then we continue recursively, picking up another factor of $1-\epsilon$ each time.

The second inequality is just replacing $\{ \tau_y^+>t \}$ with $\{ \tau_y^+>r\lfloor t/r \rfloor \}$ and the latter is a superset of the former.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The 2 points make sense, yet I am not sure how to proceed. Does (2) imply $P_x\{\tau^+_y\leq kr\}\geq k\epsilon$ or $P_x\{(k-1)r<\tau^+_y\leq kr\}\geq \epsilon$? (I do not think so). With respect to the second inequality, I agree that the second set is the superset of the first one but I do not see how a replacement proves the inequality. I apologize for asking for more details.

Comment: I understand why the second inequality works. Thank you. Are there intermediate equations or inequalities that help prove (1.17) or should the expression be directly obtained from the 2 observations you made?

Comment: @UniformIntegrability First question: no, it doesn't (as you can see by just setting $k$ large and ending up with a probability greater than $1$). What happens is that there is probability at least $\epsilon$ of a visit happening in that interval, but the first one could have happened earlier.

Comment: @UniformIntegrability Second question: basically the one intermediate equation is $P_x(\tau_y^+>kr)=P_x(\{ \text{ no visit occurred in } (0,(k-1)r] \text{ and no visit occurred in } ((k-1)r,kr])$.

Comment: Thank you very much!. Using independence one obtains: $P_x\{\tau^+_y>kr\}=P\{\tau^+_y>(k-1)r\}P\{\tau^+_y>r\} \leq  P\{\tau^+_y>(k-1)r\}(1-\epsilon) $

Comment: @UniformIntegrability The first thing isn't an equality, because these "trials" aren't independent. But you can still say that what I wrote is $P_x(\text{ no visit occurred in } ((k-1)r,kr] \mid \text{ no visit occurred in } (0,(k-1)r)) \\ P(\text{ no visit occurred in } (0,(k-1)r))$. Now we know with the Markov property that that first factor is at most $1-\epsilon$ because it's a weighted average of a bunch of probabilities each of which are at most $1-\epsilon$. We don't know what those weights are but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks again. It is wrong then to state _x(no visit occurred in ((−1), ]∣ no visit occurred in (0,(−1))) = $_x( \tau^+_y>r)$. What (2) says is that  _x(no visit occurred in ((−1), ]∣ no visit occurred in (0,(−1))) $\leq 1-\epsilon$

Comment: @UniformIntegrability I think what I wrote in the comment is illegible due to the way it is moved between multiple lines. I will write it again in the answer.

Comment: I understand why the inequality holds. Thank you very much. But, just to make sure: we cannot state that $P_x(\tau^+_y>kr|\tau^+_y>(k-1)r)=P_x(\tau^+_y>r)$?

Comment: @UniformIntegrability No, because on the LHS you will restart at time $(k-1)r$ at some random point, whereas on the RHS you are starting at $x$.